# Consultar datos al cargar la pagina Angular

Tags: javascript, laravel, angular

Amigos como estan estoy iniciando en angular y queria consultarles algo. Tengo un componente donde muestro el listado de las ordenes, Lo que quiero es que al iniciar el componente se muestren las ordenes correspondientes al mes actual que sean solo las creadas por el usuario que se logueo.

Tengo un metodo con el cual saco el usuario logueado ene el metodo onInit, pero al querer sacar las ordenes se pierde este valor y pasa el parametro como null.

En el on init tengo

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.setForm();
this.getActualUser();
this.getList(1,this.usuario_id);
```

}

en el set form tengo esto

```
public setForm(): void {
this.form = this._fb.group({
  distribuidor: null,
  cliente: null,
  producto: null,
  fecha_inicio:null,
  fecha_final:null,
  usuario_id:null,
  usuario_rol:null,
});
```

}

en el getActualUser

```
public getActualUser(): void {
this.spinner.start();
this._user.getUserProfile(this.token.auid).subscribe(
  (user) => {
    this.form.patchValue({
      usuario_id: user.data.id,
      usuario_rol: user.data.role_id,
    });
    this.usuario_id=user.data.id;
    this.usuario_rol=user.data.role_id;
    this.spinner.stop();
  },
  (err) => {
    this.alertify.error(err);
    this.spinner.stop();
  }
);
```

}

en el getList()

```
public getList(page?: number,user?:number): void {
this.spinner.start();
console.log(this.paramsToSend());
this._ticket.getTicketsListUser(page,this.paramsToSend()).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.list = res.pagination.data;
    this.totalItems = res.pagination.total;
    this.perPage = res.pagination.per_page;
    this.showResults = true;
    this.spinner.stop();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  },
  (err) => {
    this.spinner.stop();
  }
);
```

}

Entonces en el metodo getList al invocar el servicio los parametros (paramsToSend) de envio estan todos en null.

Como o donde deberia setear estas variables para que se pase en el metodo getList al cargar la pagina por primera vez

Answer (score 0):

Al ser una operación asincrona, `getActualUser` retorna los datos después de que `getList` los solicita. Para resolver esto debes de asegurarte que `getList` se llame hasta que se resuelva la suscripción.

```js
public getActualUser(): void {
  this.spinner.start();
  this._user.getUserProfile(this.token.auid).subscribe(
    (user) => {
      this.form.patchValue({
        usuario_id: user.data.id,
        usuario_rol: user.data.role_id,
      });
      this.usuario_id = user.data.id;
      this.usuario_rol = user.data.role_id;
      this.spinner.stop();
      
      //Aqui tienes que ponerlo para que los datos se obtengan en tiempo.
      this.getList(1,this.usuario_id);
      
    },
    (err) => {
      this.alertify.error(err);
      this.spinner.stop();
    }
  );
}
```

Y remueve la llamada de `getList` del `ngOnInit`.